# Ownership of Contracts with Embark

Tags: solidity, blockchain, embark

I'm using the Embark-Framework to handle my DApp development.  I made a new contract that has the public address `owner`.  Example below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;
contract MyContract {

  address public owner = msg.sender ;
  uint public creationTime = now;

  function getOwner() returns (address owner) {
    return owner;
  }

}
```

On the front-end side, I type:

```
var c = web3.eth.contract(MyContract.abi).at(MyContract.address)
c.getOwner()
```

And the output is a constantly changing string... Meaning the owner is constantly changing.  Any ideas why?

I can do the same with using the `promise()` formulation of embark (i.e., running `MyContract.getOwner().then(...)`.  Still, value keeps changing.

EDIT: Screenshots provided:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because `getOwner()` is not marked as `constant`. So what you'd be seeing is a transaction hash, not the owner. If I'm right, you'll be able to see that what it's giving you is actually *32* bytes of hexidecimal, not 20 (for an address).

But there's an even simpler way. Since you've made `owner` public, solidity has automatically made a getter for you! You can just call `c.owner()` to get the owner.

Comment: thanks, you were right on both accounts, well done!  Declaring the function `constant` worked with `getOwner()`, and calling `c.owner()` also worked. Thanks so much.

Comment: One more question @MatthewSchmidt: why do you need to mark it as `constant`?  When can you return a non constant value?  If you return anything other than the tx hash, can it be not a constant?

Comment: `constant` means that it should not effect the state of the contract, so it can (reasonably) safely be simulated by the node without calling it. Otherwise, the node will actually send a transaction, which is why it will return a transaction hash (since it isn't instant.)

Answer (score 0):

try to change the name of the return value :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;
contract MyContract {

  address public owner = msg.sender ;
  uint public creationTime = now;

  function getOwner() returns (address xowner) {
    return owner;
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: nope, doesn't fix it :(

Comment: Is it possible that it's something that has to do with the `embark-framework`? I can post a screenshot too if that's helpful...

Comment: posted a screenshot

Comment: Just following up on this, @BadrBellaj, any ideas?